# how to change character entiry to hex decimal entity in XML::Twig using perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am new to perl script, I want convert character entity to hexa decimal entity.. how can i convert this file using xml::Twig module?

File sample.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
      <text>This testing&mdash;value.</text>
    </root>
```

Output as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
      <text>This testing&#x2014;value.</text>
    </root>
```

how to include this conversion in xml twig....

Comment: What have you got so far? Your source data doesn't look like XML...

Comment: no, am define to samples to you, please don't find as xml structure, i need solution in xml::Twig module. I gave to concept only...

Comment: XML::Twig is for parsing XML. It's therefore pointless to discuss it without some valid XML.

Comment: hmmm k i accept your suggestion, i will change ....

Comment: `&mdash;` is not valid XML. (XML only [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent) `amp`, `lt`, `gt`, `quot` and `apos`.) Is this XHTML? Or is the point to fix invalid XML (which could make the request of using an XML parser problematic...).

Comment: Yes that is problem, so how to change this char entity to hex entity using perl module?